# No Audio recorded with FFMPEG ALSA Loopback

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, alsa

I am trying to record screen with audio. I played an mp4 file with audio and video in browser and I tried the command specified [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop), and tried to save output to mp4 as well as mkv files. But the screen records with no audio. I have installed Alsa loopback with

> sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
>
> modprobe snd-aloop

The outputs of `arecord -l` and `aplay -l` are [arecord -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm50B.png) [aplay -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7RZn.png)

I have tried all hw devices like `hw:0`, `hw:2`, `hw:0,1`, `hw:0,1,0`

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with FFMPEG version 4.0.3-1~18.04.york0

I have faced same issue with FFMPEG version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

The same issue is also faced in Ubuntu 16.04 with FFMPEG version 4.0.3-1~16.04.york0.

Please help me solve this. I can not use any other packages like Simple-Screen-Recorder or PulseAudio, as the command which I am trying to run for an application uses only FFMPEG and Alsa Loopback, and is not changeable.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to record the alsa Loopback with ffmpeg.

This finally did the trick:

```sh
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:Loopback,1,0 rec.wav
```

I have to admit i use pavcontrol to send audio to the Loopback device.

Comment: How do you use pavucontrol to send audio to the Loopback device?

Comment: In pavucontrol -> playback tab -> i can select the output with a pulldown for every playback source. I have the choice between "Hdmi", "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" and "Loopback Analog Stereo"